# Бог не выдаст, свинья не съест

Tags: фразеология

Думаю, все знают пословицу (или поговорку?) "Бог не выдаст, свинья не съест". Но, честно говоря, она меня повергает в некоторое недоумение. Во-первых, я не очень понимаю, в каких ситуациях она используется и что означает. Во-вторых, ее происхождение и смысл остаются для меня загадкой. Кого и кому не должен выдать Бог и при чем тут свинья? Что она не съест и почему?
Буду благодарен за разъяснения смысла и происхождения этой пословицы.

Comment: Повтор темы: http://russ.hashcode.ru/questions/10795/фразеология-бог-не-выдаст-свинья-не-съест

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Большой толково-фразеологический словарь Михельсона даёт две пословицы:

Богъ не выдастъ, свинья не съѣстъ.
Конь не выдастъ, врагъ не съѣстъ.

Здесь видна причинно-следственная связь, которую можно восстановить по варианту Даля: "Если Бог не даст, то свинья не съест" - иными словами: на всё воля Божья, в том числе и на то, окажемся ли мы в меню у свиньи.

Почему свинья должна, может или хочет кого-нибудь съесть?

Во-первых, свиней обычно едят люди, а не наоборот. Приписывание животным несвойственных им качеств и занятий тоже характерно для русских пословиц и поговорок: когда речь идёт об образном выражении чего-то совершенно нереального.
Таким образом, пословицу нужно понимать таким образом: "Если на то воля Божья, то могут произойти даже маловероятные события".

Во-вторых, свинья - животное всеядное и при определённых обстоятельствах (очень специфических) может съесть если не взрослого человека, то ребёнка. Об этом как раз идёт речь у Н. А. Некрасова в поэме "Кому на Руси жить хорошо", в главе IV "Дёмушка":

Выражает ли данная пословица фаталистическое отношение к жизни? Нет, не выражает, потому что смысловой акцент в ней сделан именно на том, что возможности человека широки за исключением того маловероятного момента, когда вмешиваются внешние, высшие силы, ну, а если такое случится, то абсолютно всё возможно... но маловероятно.

Смысл здесь скорее всего христианский. По преданию, когда младенца Христа прятали в хлеву от Ирода, то лошадь зарывала его в солому, а свинья разрывала.Отсюда вторая пословица с конём.

Таким образом, смысл сводится к следующему: на всё воля Божья, т.е. высших сил, возможен и плохой исход, но будем надеяться на лучшее, как когда-то произошло со спасением божественного младенца.

Comment: Неужели Иосиф с Марией держали свинью в своем хлеву? Думайте прежде, чем пересказывать придуманные кем-то глупости.

Comment: Ну что Вы... При чём здесь хлев Иосифа и  Марии. Речь в предании, скорее всего, идёт о хлеве, где родился Иисус:  Иосиф и Пресвятая Дева Мария отправились в город Вифлеем на перепись населения, не смогли найти себе место в городе для ночлега — слишком много было приезжих. Тогда они нашли себе приют среди гор, в пещере, куда пастухи загоняли свои стада в плохую погоду. Божия Мать спеленала его и положила в ясли, на сено. Так исполнилось предсказание пророка, который говорил, что Христос родится в Вифлееме.

Comment: К тому же речь не о Библии, а о народных преданиях, которых было множество, особенно в деревнях - пересказы странников. Пословицы и поговорки часто рождаются из таких вот пересказов, сказок.Народ "додумывает", как всё могло бы быть, детали народной жизни. Апокрифы народные, так сказать.

Comment: Еще раз прошу, не повторяйте чужие глупости. Может быть, и была такая сказка, но про кого-то другого. 


Иосиф и Мария были праведными иудеями. Никакой свиньи там даже рядом не могло быть.

Comment: Тогда уж давайте начнем с того, что Иосифа и Марии вообще могло не существовать. Первые письменные источники о событиях того времени датируются 50 годами после предполагаемой смерти Иисуса или его прототипа. И какие персонажи и сюжетные ходы там были выдуманы, а какие реально были, совершенно неизвестно. Плюс, если уж говорить о сказках, то наличие свиньи - на порядок меньшая сказка, чем "чудеса", описанные в этих текстах. :)) Свинья вас возмущает, но с "непорочным зачатием" вы не спорите? :)

Comment: «Вообще могло не существовать.» ==== Спасибо за предоставленный шанс.

Answer (score 0):

Как мне кажется, здесь речь идёт о благоприятном исходе какого-либо дела: "Не бойся, всё будет хорошо! - Бог не выдаст, свинья не съест!" "Бог не выдаст", - в смысле - не предаст (можно **выдать** замуж, а можно **выдать** врагам). А "свинья не съест", потому что свинья - животное всеядное и очень прожорливое. Вторая часть этой поговорки (а это скорее поговорка, чем пословица, так как нет поучения) как раз и призвана раскрыть именно ту семантику слова "выдаст", о которой я написал выше, а также усилить мысль о безусловном везении в грядущем свершении.

Answer (score 0):

В широком смысле эта поговорка означает "Ничего, справимся", "Все будет хорошо", "Будем живы, не помрем" и прочее в том же духе. Религиозный подтекст тут вовсе не обязателен. И употребление слова "Бог" — зачастую просто фигура речи.

Аналогично как во фразах "Слава Богу", "Не дай Бог" и т.п.

Comment: Употребление слова = фигура речи?

Comment: @shampar Фигу́ра ре́чи (ритори́ческая фигу́ра, стилисти́ческая фигу́ра, оборот речи; лат. figura от др.-греч. σχῆμα) — термин риторики и стилистики, обозначающий различные обороты речи, которые придают ей стилистическую значимость, образность и выразительность, изменяют её эмоциональную окраску.

Comment: В том числе и употребления всяких "слава Богу" и т.п. А вообще, что забавляет в этом разделе - это постоянный некропостинг.

Comment: Ещё раз. Цитата: «употребление слова "Бог" — зачастую просто фигура речи». Слово — не фигура.

Answer (score -1):

"Залупился и висит" - желудь. Чьи-то наглость и отступления от правил - тот самый желудь (залупился - дерзость,наглость), образно говоря, который все же побаивается быть съденным "свиньей"  ("подложить свинью" - подставить ..), и надеется проскочить в своей дерзости выигрышно для себя и не заметно.
    Ну что вы .., мыслим образно ... Все ж логично, изречения народ носил по свету сарафанным радио, ни библия, ни высеченные заумной латынью на камне истины..)), а где народ, там образность иносказаниями, смешанными с жаргонами, сленгом и зашеренными изъяснениями так, чтоб самому простому человеку, без знания глав Библии.., по знанию простой жизни))), все было ясно ;-) .

Comment: Дерзкий жёлудь прячет нагло... Побаивается, залупился и висит. «Мыслим образно».

Answer (score -2):

Последнее правильно! Господь молчит и вы молчите, тогда плохие люди ни о чём не узнают (свинье не достанется)!!! Все просто, не надо приписывать заумные мысли простому народу, который это придумал. Так часто говорят, когда просят о чем то умолчать в коллективе, особенно перед начальством. Сейчас больше употребляют "Меньше знает, крепче спит".